# Why Can't i update a variable of class from another class in android(Java)?

Tags: java, android, class

I want to update this num variable from different classes through this Methods .
but it show '0' when i display it

```
public class ResultNum extends AppCompatActivity{

private  int num;


public int ResultNum1(){

   return num;
}


public void yesMethod(int i){

    num = i+num;

}
```

Here is Another class

```
 yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.yesMethod(2);


        }
    });
```

and also I've some other classes as well which passes different numbers

here's code for displaying number

```
 TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_number);
   int x = result.ResultNum1();
    t.setText(""+x);
```

i also tried

```
 TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_number);
    t.setText(""+result.ResultNum1());
```

so What exactly i need to do now?

Comment: You need to call `.yesMethod()` on same `Object`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also please read and follow the 
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: you should setText after pressing click. Do you set setText after button click?

Comment: Actually i am calling yes method from a class and ResultNum1 from a different class.

Comment: But is it the same instance ? The origine don't matter, the instance used does. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: why not use static member variable ?

Comment: You need to make `num` variable as `static.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, you should either declare `int num` as `static` or make sure that all your methods across application use the same instance of `ResultNum` class.